# ajax request to public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a JavaScript file making an ajax request to a file containing json data. The json data file is located in the public folder of Rails, however, the ajax request is returning a 404 not found error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/data/album1.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone make a suggestion about what url to set for the ajax request, or where to put the json file if not in the public folder?  Note, in addition to the url shown in the code below, I also tried `url: 'data/album1.json'` but it gave me the same result.

```
if (this._index === null){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'public/data/album1.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not including the `public` in the url, but including the slash:

`/data/album1.json`

Comment: Sure it's located in [rails root]/public/data/album1.json?

Comment: yes, it's there, but do I have to set a route for it in the routes file?

Comment: Also, make sure `config.serve_static_assets = true` in config/environments/development.rb. You don't need a route for it; that's only for dynamic content.

Comment: I just read in the json file and made it available at a root within the app directory, however, I'd still like to know if this is possible.

Comment: I put the file in the config directory and read it in from the Controller, rendering json. Set a route to the controller in the routes.rb file, and made the ajax request to the route I set in routes.rb, which triggered the read of the file in the controller